# $.parseJSON shows error in console only for some sites

Tags: jquery, wordpress

The following code throws an error in console **Unexpected token u at position 0** which was because the data attribute content was not set in some cases which resulted in $.parseJSON taking value "undefined".

```
var save_block = $('#timber_box');
var data_block = save_block.attr('data-content');
data_block = $.parseJSON(data_block);
```

I have fixed this by checking whether the data attribute exists.

The problem is while i was testing it locally, I haven't received any error in console. I tested the same in two live sites. The issue was only in one site. Every site has same jQuery version. Is there anything I am missing. I am testing in a WordPress.

Comment: This does not look like real programming issue as presented, more like debugging question.

Comment: Ok then, please guide me to the right platform so I can find a solution

Comment: It is not about the platform, but the way you do debugging. There must be something different on those sites, my first guess is: check where/when your code executes, cause if you see the data-content attribute present in your browser, then the code executes before the same element appeared in DOM tree. But that's just a guess, better use your browser tools, check what's on page, what script are called and when, is there any other error etc.

Comment: Note : As of jQuery 3.0, `$.parseJSON`is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use the native JSON.parse method instead

Comment: Wordpress haven't updated jQuery versions. So still using old one